# How to print errno while saving the value from function?

Tags: c, io, errno

I am not able to open/create a file properly using open() function, so I thought that using errno messages will help me to figure out the reason. However I don't know how to set the if(), so it prints me the error.
I know the code like this should work:

```
if(open(handle,O_RDWR | O_CREAT) == -1){
      printf("%s\n",strerror(errno));
}
```

but what if I want to save the value from open() to my variable and IF it is -1 then print the error as well? I don't want to call open() twice for this and I don't know how to assign it if it is ok and how to print error if not.

```
 #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <fcntl.h>
    #include <ctype.h>
    #include <sys/types.h>
    #include <sys/stat.h>
    #include <string.h>
    #include <errno.h>


    int main(int argc, char **argv){
        int handle,i,help;
        int *array = malloc(5*sizeof(int));
        float *red = malloc(5*sizeof(int));

        array[0]=5;
        array[1]=4;
        array[2]=3;
        array[3]=2;
        array[4]=1;

        handle = open(argv[1], O_RDWR | O_CREAT);
        if(handle == -1){
            printf("%s\n",strerror(errno));
        }

        printf("handle 1 %d\n",handle);
        write(handle,array,20);
        close(handle);

        handle = open(argv[1], O_RDONLY);
        lseek(handle,0,SEEK_SET);
        printf("handle %d\n",handle);
        help=read(handle,&red,20);
        printf("pomoc %d\n",help);
        for(i=0; i<5; i++){
            printf("%d\n",(int)red[i]);
        }
        close(handle);
        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: this is my "try" code because I am not sure how read() function works, so I wanted to try if I can throw any type of pointer there and read any amount of bytes and if it will work, but I cannot even get past the opening part.

Comment: Note that you should not continue as if the handle was open after reporting the error.  And the error should be reported on the standard error stream, not on standard output.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is not with assigning to a variable, it's the way you're calling `open`:

```
handle = open(argv[1], O_RDWR|O_CREAT); // wrong number of arguments
if (handle == -1) {
    printf("%s\n",strerror(errno));
}
```

When you use `O_CREAT`, you must give `open` *three* arguments.  If you don't, the behavior is undefined.  *By accident*, you were getting a −1 error return when you had the `open` call inside the `if`, and a nonnegative return value when you assigned it to a variable.

Unless you have a concrete reason to do otherwise, the third argument to `open` should be the magic number `0666`.  (The most common concrete reason to do otherwise is that you are creating a file which will hold *secret* information; then you use `0600`.)  (The leading zero is required.) There *are* symbolic constants that can be used for the third argument to `open` but, once you know what numeric "modes" mean, the symbolic constants are actually harder to read.  [Here is a detailed explanation of "modes" in both symbolic and numeric forms.](http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Permissions.html)

Incidentally, when a system call fails you should always print *both* `strerror(errno)` *and* the name of the offending file (if any):

```
handle = open(argv[1], O_RDWR|O_CREAT, 0666);
if (handle == -1) {
    printf("%s: %s\n", argv[1], strerror(errno));
    exit(1);
}
```

And you should think about whether you should be using `O_EXCL` or `O_TRUNC`.

Comment: Or consider `O_TRUNC` if not using `O_EXCL`?

Answer (score 1):

The proper way to do this is:

```
    if((handle=open(argv[1], O_RDWR|O_CREAT, 0666)) == -1){
```

Note that the `pmode` argument is required for `O_CREAT`.

Comment: Well what are those modes? I've seen more some talks about it but I haven't seen any tuts about it so far. I am on Linux btw.

Comment: `_S_IREAD` and `_S_IWRITE` are nonstandard.  The third argument to `open` should almost always be `0666`; the most important exception is for files that contain _secrets_, for which use `0600`.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're doing it just right; just save the return value of `open()` to a variable, then compare that against -1. Fine.

Note that this is broken:

```
float *red = malloc(5*sizeof(int));
```

since there's no guarantee that a `float` is the same size as an `int`, this is wrong and very confusing. It's better to not repeat the type in the `malloc()` since that risks introducing this error. Instead, do:

```
float * const red = malloc(5 * sizeof *red);
```

This uses `sizeof *red` to compute `sizeof (float)`, while making sure the type is that of an actual pointer in your program. Also note use of `const` to protect against `red` being re-assigned later, which might create a memory leak.

Comment: I am just not sure because when I do it this way suddenly handle is not -1 but 0, and it doesn't know what to print I guess. About the allocation I know it cannot be used normally I said, I am just trying what can be done with the low level functions, but since you picked it out, can I ask how to do it then? I have to write one byte of unsigned char and then random number of floats, all in binary. How should I read them back into memory?

Comment: @ligazetom That's an entierly different question about how to encode/serialize data, and answering it in a comment to this question goes against how this site is supposed to work. Please post a relevant question, or search, I know that has come up loads of times before.